# SQL Union From a Single Row

Tags: mysql, union

I am trying to union a single row to itself. 
The Database has a table with a lot of columns (48 columns) and I would like to group it so that the columns would be viewable by thee for the result.

The database looks like this:

Table: `RACEBETS`

```
    RACENO|BETTER1|BET1|STAT1|BETTER2|BET2|STAT2|BETTER3|BET3|STAT3|BETTER4|...
    R01   |BT1    |200 |1    |BT2    |500 |1    |BT3    |500 |0    |BT4    |...
```

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT 
    ITEMS.ITEM43, ITEMS.ITEM44, ITEMS.ITEM45, ITEMS.ITEM46
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         'TYPE1' AS ITEM43, RACEBETS.BETTER1 AS ITEM44, 
         COALESCE(RACEBETS.BET1,'0') AS ITEM45, 
         COALESCE(RACEBETS.STAT1,'0') AS ITEM46, 
         RACEBETS.RACENO, '1' AS ORD 
     FROM 
         RACEBETS 
     WHERE 
         RACEBETS.BETTER1 IS NOT NULL

     UNION

     SELECT 
         'TYPE1' AS ITEM43, RACEBETS.BETTER2 AS ITEM44, 
         COALESCE(RACEBETS.BET2,'0') AS ITEM45, 
         COALESCE(RACEBETS.STAT2,'0') AS ITEM46, 
         RACEBETS.RACENO, '2' AS ORD 
     FROM 
         RACEBETS 
     WHERE 
         RACEBETS.BETTER2 IS NOT NULL

     UNION 

     SELECT 
         'TYPE2' AS ITEM43, RACEBETS.BETTER3 AS ITEM44, 
          COALESCE(RACEBETS.BET3,'0') AS ITEM45, 
          COALESCE(RACEBETS.STAT3,'0') AS ITEM46, 
          RACEBETS.RACENO, '3' AS ORD 
      FROM 
          RACEBETS 
      WHERE 
          RACEBETS.BETTER3 IS NOT NULL

      UNION
         some more... ) ITEMS, SCHEDULE
INNER JOIN 
    RACE ON SCHEDULE.SCHEDCODE = RACE.SCHEDCODE
WHERE 
    SCHEDULE.SCHEDCODE = '01'
    AND RACE.RACENO = '001'
    AND ITEMS.RACENO = RACE.RACENO
ORDER BY 
    ITEMS.ORD ASC
```

This shows my desired output:

```
    ITEM43|ITEM44|ITEM45|ITEM46
    TYPE1 |BT1   |200   |1
    TYPE1 |BT2   |500   |1
    TYPE2 |BT3   |500   |0
    TYPE2 |.....
```

I believe my current query will retrieve all rows before the union and would cause the database to be slow.

The questions:

1. Is there a trick to union from a single select since I would be retrieving all my required files from a single select?
2. Is it more efficient if I add the "where clause" and "join clause" into the individual select statement before using union?

Thanks!

Comment: This would be be for mysql

Answer (score 0):

I won't argue that this any better than you are doing, but it does operate from just one SELECT from racebets.

```
SELECT thebets.ITEM44,thebets.ITEM45,thebets.ITEM46
 FROM
(
SELECT
    CONCAT('TYPE',map.item) ITEM44,

CASE map.item
    WHEN '1' THEN
        racebets.better2  
    WHEN '2' THEN
        racebets.better3  
    END AS betkey,
CASE map.item
    WHEN '1' THEN
        COALESCE(RACEBETS.BET2,'0') 
    WHEN '2' THEN
        COALESCE(RACEBETS.BET3,'0')
    END AS ITEM45,  
CASE map.item
    WHEN '1' THEN
        COALESCE(RACEBETS.STAT2,'0')
    WHEN '2' THEN
    COALESCE(RACEBETS.STAT3,'0')
    END AS ITEM46

from racebets 
join (
    select '1' item
    union all
    select '2'
) map
) thebets
WHERE thebets.betkey IS NOT NULL
```

The 'trick' I picked up from SO a few days ago, but cannot find the post now. It joins to a derived table that is used as a map to unpivot the results.